# Order of product of group elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-commutative group of order $N$, and let $x, y \in G$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the orders of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Can we say anything non-trivial about the order of $xy$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? If it helps, you may assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: No, it is more-or-less answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130697/how-to-find-quotients-of-infinite-triangle-groups-or-von-dyck-groups

Comment: Only in the comments, to be fair...

Comment: To be more explicit: for all three positive integers $a,b,c$, there exist a finite group and elements $x,y$ such that $x,y,xy$ have order $a,b,c$, with the only trivial restriction: if one of $a,b,c$ is $1$, then the other two are equal.

Comment: Let me also mention that the case when $a,b,c$ are all even is trivial: one can then find three such elements in the direct product of three dihedral groups $D_a\times D_b\times D_c$, each with generators of order two $u,v$, namely $x=(uv,u,v)$, $y=(v,uv,u)$, $xy=(u,v,vu)$.

Comment: Given $a,b,c\ge 2$, estimating/computing the smallest size $n$ such that there is such a pair in the symmetric group $S_n$, looks like an interesting problem. For $a,b,c$ even, the above gives an upper bound of $a+b+c$.

Comment: YCor, your example is interesting to me, but I didn't quite understand how $u$ and $v$ are picked. I understand that you can pick $u$ to be a generator of order 2 (this represents a reflection), but how are there two distinct generators of order 2? In the dihedral group of order $2n$, shouldn't there be one generator of order 2 and one of order $n$ (the rotation part)?

Answer (score 23):

The following theorem (which does not take the order $N$ of the group $G$ into account) shows that all possible combinations of $a$, $b$ and the order of $xy$ are possible. See Theorem 1.64 from [Milne's course notes on group theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf).

> For any integers $a,b,c > 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ has order $a$, $y$ has order $b$, and $xy$ has order $c$.

Comment: :what can we say about such a group,....it was asked in exam that "consider such group with above property,then G, (1)cannot be cyclic,(2) G has to non abelion......which one is true,1) or 2)?

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that the answer is "very little", unless you are looking for bounds on the order of $xy$ in terms of $N$ or something like that.

**Example.** Let's focus on the example $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. It is well-known that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf Z/2 * \mathbf Z/3 &\stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z)\\
x &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\\
y &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $x$ and $y$ are the generators with $x^2 = 1$ and $y^3 = 1$. The product $xy$ maps to
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
which has infinite order. For any $n \in \mathbf N$, the surjection
$$\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z) \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z/n)$$
gives a finite group of order roughly $n^3$ in which $xy$ has exact order $n$.

**Example.** Another example, still with $a = 2$ and $b = 3$, is the group
$$G = \mathbf Z/n \wr S_3 = (\mathbf Z/n)^3 \rtimes S_3,$$
where multiplication is defined by
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,\sigma)(b_1,b_2,b_3,\tau) = (a_1+b_{\sigma(1)},a_2+b_{\sigma(2)},a_3+b_{\sigma(3)},\sigma\tau).$$
Then one easily checks that $x = (1,-1,0,(12))$ has order $2$ and $y = (0,0,0,(123))$ has order $3$, and $xy = (1,-1,0,(23))$ has order $2n$. This time we get any *even* number as the order of $xy$, inside a group of order $6n^3$.